# Why did Pepper have the key to the Fulcrum?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-blacklist

In The Blacklist Season 2, Ep 5, "The Front", Reddington got a key from Beck's girlfriend, Pepper. The key is later revealed to be a key for the Fulcrum.

Why would this rather random person have the key to a blackmail file supposedly in Reddington's possession?